# How can I specify a row span for a Xamarin grid element in C#?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's the effect I am trying to achieve:

[image]

So far I have created a Grid called `grid` coded this:

```
        grid.Children.Add(new BaseButton("A"), 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(new BaseButton("B"), 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(new BaseButton("C"), 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(new BaseButton("D"), 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(new BaseButton("E"), 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(new BaseButton("F"), 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(new BaseButton("G"), 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(new BaseButton("H"), 0, 0);
```

My question is, how can I achieve the row span of three for the Button A in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.grid.igridlist-1.add?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Grid_IGridList_1_Add_Xamarin_Forms_View_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

```
public void Add (Xamarin.Forms.View view, int left, int right, int top, int bottom);
```

- left is the first column of the span (0 based)
- right is the last column of the span (0 based)
- top is the first row of the span (0 based)
- bottom is the last row of the span (0 based)

so would use

```
grid.Children.Add(new BaseButton("A"), 0, 2, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize there was a constructor with four arguments. Can you also in your answer include how to do the button B just so I can get a better idea of how to do them all.